# Customise notification popups

Tags: gnome-shell, notification, notify-osd, notify-send

Some of my applications show notification messages in this style:

[image]

Even when I'm running Ubuntu Gnome (as opposed to i3wm), a few apps show notifications in this style instead of going to Gnome's notification centre (not to mention the style looks completely out of place), and I can't figure out which daemon is controlling these pop-ups, nor can I figure out how to customise them to make them less ugly. I discovered that I can send notifications in this style if I use the `notify-send` command I can create pop-ups in that style.

```
notify-send 'Hello world!' 'This is an example notification.' --icon=dialog-information
```

My questions:

1. Which daemon/app is controlling this notification centre?
2. Can I direct the notifications there to Gnome's notification centre so all my notifications are in one place?
3. How can I customise the appearance of these pop-ups?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04